# Output of the untreated exception mixing up with output of the program

Tags: java, exception

When i ran this program in java

```
package test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("line"+i);
        }
        System.out.flush();
        int x=1/0;
    }
}
```

i was expecting to have output like this:

```
line0
line1
line2
line3
line4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:8)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

but instead output looked like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
line0
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:8)
line1
line2
line3
line4

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and after i ran it again:

```
line0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
line1
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:9)
line2
line3
line4

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and so on. The lines or Exception message mix up with output randomly.
I tried putting `System.out.flush();` before `int x=1/0;` but it didn't help.
This also happened when i made my own Exception(it extended RuntimeException) and when i made NullPointerException.  Why does this happens and how can i fix it?

Comment: I think this is because you are dealing with two different OutputStreams (one is System.err for the exception and one is System.out). The proper way would be to use a logger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs because exceptions are printed using `System.err` which is a different `PrintStream` than `System.out`.  If you want exceptions to be printed using `System.out`, then you can call `System#setErr`:

```
System.setErr(System.out);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("line"+i);
}

int x = 1 / 0;
```

Output:

```
line0
line1
line2
line3
line4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Test/test.Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

Comment: This solution works but is there any other way you can do it? And also i couldn't replicate this problem with IndexOutOfBoundsException when i was using ArrayList but i could  do it with int[] which is strange to me. Can you explain a bit more how this occurred?

Comment: What other way would you like to do it?  And I don’t know what you’re talking about with `ArrayList` and `int[]`, but it sounds like you need to ask another question

Comment: I don't really understand why does output mix up. For example this code
`List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
 int x=list.get(3);`
will throw exception that will never mix up with rest of the output, but this code
`List<Integer> list=Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
 int x=list.get(3);`
or this code
`int[] arr={1,2,3};
 int x=arr[3];`
will throw exception that will mix up with the rest of output if i don't reassign System.err to System.out. I would like if i could stop the mixing up without that reassignment since in the first case it works without my intervention.